# To check the md5 of files to check for modification using ant

Tags: ant

I am working to develop a script.In a project there is a folder which contains files which i need to which whether they got modified or not so and its need to be done using md5 ad ant so request you let me know how can it can be done using md5 and ant

Comment: will ant will be able to recognize that file has been modified by calculating its checksum...lets say we run the ant script for a file.It generate a 32 it number and we modify the content of that file and then again we run the ant script can we programatically check for the modification of file

Comment: Standard ANT feature. Check the modified selector in the ANT doco: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html